# Need help limiting array/optimizing axios responses

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have something like `/url/{category}`.

This is the code to fetch some of these on the main page:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            topnews:[],
            newsfive:[],
            categories: { 
                tshirts:'',
                shirts:'',
                shoes:'',
                useful:'', 
            }
        }
    },
    methods() {
        async getAll(){
            axios.all([
                axios.get(`/topnews`),
                axios.get(`/news`),
                axios.get(`/tshirts`),
                axios.get(`/shirts`),
                axios.get(`/shoes`),
                axios.get(`/useful`)])
                .then(axios.spread((topnews, news, tshirts, shirts, shoes, useful) => {
                    news.data.length = 5;
                    tshirts.data.length = 5
                    shirts.data.length = 5
                    shoes.data.length = 5
                    useful.data.length = 5
                    // How to limit these appropriately? 

                    this.newsfive = news.data;
                    this.topnews = topnews.data;

                    this.categories = {
                        tshirts: tshirts.data,
                        shirts: shirts.data,
                        shoes: shoes.data,
                        useful: useful.data,
                    }
                })).catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
    created()  {
        this.getAll() 
    }
}
```

This works, but If I change the route to `/tshirts` and use browser back to the main page, I get:

> typeerror content read-only property

Also is it possible to combine this into a single array instead of creating 7 different divs like:

```html
<div v-for="tshirts,key in categories.tshirts" :key="categories.tshirts.slug">
    <img :src="tshirts.thumb" class="img-responsive" width=100%/>
    <p>{{tshirts.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Instead have something like a filtered computed axios response and then just use a single div?

```html
<div v-for="item,key in categories(tshirts)" :key="categories(item.slug)">
```

How can I limit the axios array response size?

Comment: Style, grammar and formatting.

Comment: It seems like you're already limiting the response size after receiving it. The error related to the route change seems to be the issue you're trying to solve. What client side router are you using? Can you share a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response and thanks for trying to help. I solved it instead of using news.data.length, I put news.data.slice(0,5) as @Alexander Yakushev suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Category.vue` to render only category content

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, key) in category" :key="item.slug">
      <img :src="item.thumb" class="img-responsive" width=100% />
      <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            category: { }
        }
    },
    methods() {
        getCategory() {
          axios.get(`/${this.$route.params.category}`)                
               .then((response) => {
                  this.category = response.data.slice(0, 5);                    
               }).catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
    created()  {
        this.getCategory() 
    }
}
</script>
```

And in `App.vue` add `router-link` to all categories

```
<template>
   <nav>
      <router-link to="{ name: 'category', params: {category: 'tshirts'} }">T-Shirts</router-link>
      <router-link to="{ name: 'category', params: {category: 'shirts'} }">Shirts</router-link>
     <!-- and other -->
   </nav>
   <main>
      <router-view></router-view>
   </main
</template>
```

Don't forger about `vue-router`

```
import Category from "./Category.vue"

routes = [
  {
    name: "category",
    path: "/:categoryId",
    component: Category
  }
]
```

Comment: Well I need to fetch and display items on the main page, not to create routerlinks for the items pointing to a different page, but anyway slice(0,5) did exactly what I wanted, and I take the code you gave as a bonus, thank you for that. Just a quick note for future readers is that it won't display anything if there aren't atleast 5 records - obvious, but worth mentioning. That is not a problem for me anyway.

Comment: Yes, I made mistake. There should be `slice(0, 5)`